# 502 error sending post request to app running on ngrok

Tags: javascript, reactjs, express

I have a react front end app that I am running locally with ngrok and from this I am trying to send a fetch post request to the server that I have added to the project - react app contained within client folder and the express server contained within server folder.

So the client fetch post request does hit the server endpoint as it consoles the empty body and on the ngrok it says POST / but doesnt give a status!? . Yet in the front-end it gives a bad request 502 error and a CORS error, I have tried enabling CORS on both sides:

here is the code (the consoles work):

Client:

```
  storeEmailData(domain, emailAddress, email, storeName) {

console.log('consoling the data IN API FILE' + domain);
console.log('consoling the data IN API FILE' + emailAddress);
fetch('https://3ecec55f.ngrok.io/', { 
  method: 'POST',
  mode: 'cors',
  data: {
    domain: domain,
    emailAddress: emailAddress,
    email: email,
    storeName: storeName,

  }

}, {mode: 'cors'} )

.then(function(response) {
  console.log('response' + response);
}).then(function(body) {
  console.log(body);
});
}
```

Server:

```
var app = express();
var db = require('./data_db.js')
var cors = require('cors');
app.use(cors());
var bodyParser = require('body-parser')

app.use(bodyParser.json())

app.post('/', function (req, res) {
   console.log('the data' + JSON.stringify(req.body))


});
```

So the server just consoles an empty body.
Here within the front-end are the errors:

```
api.js:25 POST https://3ecec55f.ngrok.io/ 502 (Bad 
Gateway)
storeEmailData @ api.js:25
ReturnsSettings._this.saveDetails @ ReturnsSettings.js:45
onClick @ ReturnsSettings.js:66
settings:1 Access to fetch at 'https://3ecec55f.ngrok.io/' 
from origin 'https://c2bca71d.ngrok.io' has been blocked 
by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is 
present on the requested resource. If an opaque response 
serves your needs, set the request's mode to 'no-cors' to 
fetch the resource with CORS disabled.
settings:1 Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Failed to 
fetch
```

any help would be greatly appreciated, thanks!!

Comment: it does appear in the console but it's an empty object {}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several issues with that `fetch` call, not least that your server is expecting you to send JSON, but you're not doing that. You've passed a simple object as the `data` parameter to `fetch`, but [`fetch` doesn't support that](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/fetch). You probably meant `body`, but valid options for `body` are:

> `body`: Any body that you want to add to your request: this can be a `Blob`, `BufferSource`, `FormData`, `URLSearchParams`, or `USVString` object.

Nothing is going to guess you're sending JSON.

Overall, the issues are:

1. Using `data` rather than `body`.
2. Using an object instead of a string (JSON = string).
3. Not identifying a `Content-Type` (to say you're sending JSON), so the default URI-encoded form will be assumed.
4. Passing a *third* argument to `fetch`, but `fetch` only accepts two.
5. Not checking for non-network failure of the `fetch`. (**Lots** of people make this mistake, so many I [wrote it up](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2018/06/common-fetch-errors.html) on my anemic little blog.)
6. Not retrieving the body of the `fetch` response.

Fixing those:

```
fetch('https://3ecec55f.ngrok.io/', { 
  method: 'POST',
  mode: 'cors',
  headers: {                                       // *** 3
    "Content-Type": "application/json"             // *** 3
  }                                                // *** 3
  body: JSON.stringify({                           // *** 1, 2
    domain: domain,
    emailAddress: emailAddress,
    email: email,
    storeName: storeName,
  })                                               // *** 2
})                                                 // *** 4
.then(function(response) {
  if (!response.ok) {                              // *** 5
    throw Error("HTTP status " + response.status); // *** 5
  }                                                // *** 5
  return response.xyz();                           // *** 6
}).then(function(body) {
  console.log(body);
});
```

...where `xyz` is [`text`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Body/text), [`json`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Body/json), [`blob`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Body/blob), [`arrayBuffer`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Body/arrayBuffer), or [`formData`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Body/formData) depending on what your server is replying with.

Side note: You don't need the `mode` option. When you're passing a string in as the first argument, the [default mode](https://fetch.spec.whatwg.org/#concept-request-request) is `"cors"` (it's a bit tricky to find that in there, but it's there). (But you might want it as emphasis for any readers of the code who may not know that.)

Comment: Thanks for your post, I'm just going through it now and taking notes, I copied and pasted the fetch POST request online without researching how it actually works, a lesson learnt there.